# Installed on Subdomain Civimail is blank

Tags: wordpress, civimail, installation

I just installed civi 4.7.27 on Wordpress 4.9.1 into a subdomain example.mysite.com 
The civimail New Mailing page is blank and the System Status page is blank. Other pages are probably blank too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I want to let everyone know that I have resolved this issue.  Apparently when installing Civi into a subdomain, you need to configure the resource urls to absolute paths instead of relying on the short codes.  See screenshot below.  If you ever have this issue, try making your resource urls look like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please double/triple check that the paths you have set for Directories and Resources (both under Admin > System Settings) are correct.

Comment: Thank  you for your reply. I added two more screenshots to show the resource urls and directory settings.  I did not enter that information. It was automatically entered during the installation. I don't know if it is correct or not for a subdomain.  Is there something different I should try there?

Comment: do you have access via a Control Panel or something so you can actually work out where those folders are?

Comment: Yes I do have cpanel access.  I dont know which folders and files though.

Comment: sounds like you need to do some exploring or find an expert that can help. if you re-read the 'installing on Wordpress' documentation you should get some fairly strong clues

Comment: That is why I am here asking for experienced people to help me. I found those folders. Since you brought it up, I assume there is something in there you want me to look at.  As far as I can tell the URLs are correct. When I disable asset caching the pages load properly. I dont think we want asset caching disabled though. Does that maybe shed some light on what the problem is?

Comment: sorry fdam - i hope someone who knows WP more than I do can come along and shed some light for you. I was just making the first 'off top of my head' suggestion as we have often seen such blank pages being resolved by getting those paths correct.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. I m thinking its the paths too and that they are supposed to look a certain way in a subdomain.