# Case Types page 'blank'

Tags: wordpress, error, civicase

When I go to Administer > CiviCase > Case Types, that page has no content on it and the breadcrumb link at the top just says 'CiviCRM'.

In the web console, I get this error when loading that page (I've removed the domain and added spaces to keep links from showing in the post):

GET h ttp :// **.******.org/go/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/angular-modules.a136d84bc8cc935bcae2e81386c212ea.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/a/:198

GET h ttp ://**.******.org/go/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/angular-modules.a136d84bc8cc935bcae2e81386c212ea.js 404

VM6993 admin.php:199

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] h ttp ://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=crmApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.11%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DcrmApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A6%3A426%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A25%3A235%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A24%3A282)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A25%3A20%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A40%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A7%3A371)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A39%3A382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A43%3A381)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A21%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Gc%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.mediationla.org%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DQcNK7%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4692
    at q (angular.js:325)
    at g (angular.js:4653)
    at fb (angular.js:4575)
    at c (angular.js:1809)
    at Gc (angular.js:1830)
    at se (angular.js:1715)
    at HTMLDocument. (angular.js:32616)
    at i (jquery.min.js?r=QcNK7:2)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:38
(anonymous) @ angular.js:4692
q @ angular.js:325
g @ angular.js:4653
fb @ angular.js:4575
c @ angular.js:1809
Gc @ angular.js:1830
se @ angular.js:1715
(anonymous) @ angular.js:32616
i @ jquery.min.js?r=QcNK7:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js?r=QcNK7:2
ready @ jquery.min.js?r=QcNK7:2
K @ jquery.min.js?r=QcNK7:2

angular.js:38

Comment: are you using something other than the default civicase component from /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fcomponent&reset=1 eg are you trying https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase

Comment: i am not suggesting you should use the latter - just sprang to mind when i saw angular errors everywhere

Comment: I enabled the CiviCase component from inside CiviCRM (Administer > System Settings > Components).

Comment: and no warnings in your 'system status' page?

Comment: The 'System Status' page (Administer > Administration Console > System Status) looks like my current 'Case Types' page: no content & just the 'CiviCRM' link at the top.

And the footer of 'System Status' page, next to where it says 'Powered by CiviCRM 5.6.1', it says 'System Status: Error' and it's highlighted in pink.

Also when I click the link to the 'System Status' page in the menu bar, it loads
h ttp: //**.********.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/a/#/status
.... but changes to ....
h ttp: //**.********.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/status

Comment: Glad you sorted it. generally if one thing isn't working it is worth checking if other things are misfiring too

Answer (score 2):

FIXED. I have CiviCRM installed on a subdomain. Using the advice in this answer: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/21878/6594 I changed the URLs on the 'Resource URLs' page (Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs) from relative URLs with shortcode (ex. [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/) to absolute URLs (ex. http://***.******.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute). That made all of the pages that were appearing blank work properly.